# Ionic3 html is wrong after pop from other page and close keyboard

Tags: html, css, keyboard, ionic3

Problem scenario:

1. Lets say you have **Div** with 45px margin-top in page 1 content.
2. Push button and nav.push to page 2
3. enter text on textarea
4. touch anywhere in the screen to force the keyboard to close
5. hit soft back button.

**The problem:** the **Div** now is presented at much less then 45px margin from top and you cannot scroll up. Happening on Android device and not happening on android emulator.

**Page1.html:**

```
<style>

.testMargin
{
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  font-size: 20;
}

.myButton
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 30%
}

</style>

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Page1</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
     <div class="testMargin"><span>TITLE</span></div>
     <br>
     <button class="myButton" (click)="gotoPage2()">Go to page 2</button>  
</ion-content>
```

**Page1.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page2Page} from '../page2/page2';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
})
export class Page1Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

    gotoPage2()
    {
        this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);
    }
}
```

**page2.html**

```
  <style>
  .edit
  {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
        </style>

        <ion-header>
          <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>Page2</ion-title>
          </ion-navbar>
        </ion-header>


        <ion-content >
          <br><br>
          <ion-input class="edit" maxlength="20"></ion-input>
        </ion-content>
```

**Page2.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html',
})
export class Page2Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
}
```

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\sodedkor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.16.0
 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0
 global packages:
 cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
 local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
 Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3
 Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.7.1
 System:
 Node : v6.9.1
 npm : 5.5.1
 OS : Windows 8.1
 Environment Variables:
 ANDROID_HOME : not set
 Misc:
 backend : pro
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: If desperate, please provide the code to reproduce on stackblitz.  You haven't given us alot of details

Comment: Sure, I was able now to repro with much less amount of code. Still need help. I changed the scenario above and added photos to show before and after the operation.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Felix9607 I was able to fix it:

I added the following in the variables.scss:

```
.scroll-content {
    margin-top: 57px !important;
}

ion-page > ion-content > fixed-content {
    margin-top: 57px !important;
}
```

The reason is that .scroll-content and fixed-content are being overwrite to 0 upon loosing focus from a text area.